# How to do exact complete text match in mongo text index, not exact substring match

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have 3 text(tx_field1,tx_field2,tx_field3) fields in mongo document and created a compound text index on three of them.

```
createIndex({ "tx_field1": "text", "tx_field3": "text", "tx_field3": "text" })
```

I have to match exact text on these 3 fields. Consider below are the documents.

```
 {
     "tx_field1" : "Control Number",
     "tx_field2" : "Education & Employment History",
     "tx_field3" : "Expires"
 }
 {
   "tx_field1" : "Self Identify",
   "tx_field2" : "Form",
   "tx_field3" : "Education"
 }
```

I am using the below query to match exact text

```
{ $text: { $search: "\"Education\"","$caseSensitive": true }
```

The query returns the above two documents because both the documents contain the exact phrase. Is there a way to match the entire document key such that only the second document is returned,so that is only matches `Education` not `Education & Employment History`

The only way I could do that is by the following below query

```
{ $text: { $search: "\"Education\"","$caseSensitive": true },
    $or : [
            {
                "tx_field1":"Education"
            },{
                "tx_field2":"Education"
            },{
                "tx_field3":"Education"
            }    
          ]}
```

Comment: _"Is there a way to match the entire document key"_ : Then you don't need the text index. You can try single field index on each field.

Comment: @prasad_ single field index has maximum of 1024 bytes. I'm using the text index for fuzzy matching also, in a certain case i need to match the entire key. Since there is a limit on index of 1024 bytes cannot create single field index. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Index-Key-Limit

Comment: How does that limit creation of index?

Comment: well, as far as I know, and after a quick search, MongoDb text search can't work like this, you need to take a walk around like what you suggest, another stage to filter the initial results, or use find instead of text search.

Comment: @prasad_it mongo won't let you create the index.

Comment: @MoussabKbeisy i created a hash index for now and it is working fine. The query performance is good.Since normal index cannot be created on fields with large text length. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/